# macOS Grapher recursive function

Tags: grapher

Can grapher in macOS work with recursive functions???

If so how? There doesn't seem to be an obvious way and there are no answers to this online.

Thanks

Comment: Please give an example of a recursive function. I had never heard of that term.

Comment: Recursive functions are for programming I don't think they apply here.

Comment: Like f(1) = x and then f(x) = 2x + f(x-1)

Comment: Why use Grapher rather than, say, a computer algebra system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was looking for this myself and was a bit disappointed at the dismissive comments under your question. Fortunately, it is quite simple: Choose “Equation > New Equation from Template… > Other > Series”.

**Edit:** The best resource on Grapher I know is [this PDF](http://y.barois.free.fr/grapher/Documentation_files/GCXENManual16042014A.pdf). It is a bit hard to read at times because it has so much content, but it is an invaluable resource if you want to make full use of Grapher. You can find recursive functions under “Sequences”.